# Can't play mp3 file over HTTP via AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm trying to play MP3 file via AVPlayer:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://transom.org/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/stereo_40kbps.mp3?_=7")!
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
player.play()
```

But I'm getting the next log:

```
2017-09-26 21:57:07.906598+0300 MyApp[7558:1177816] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}
```

I guess it's because of iOS 11 and Xcode 9, but I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Does your app have App Transport Security settings to allow non-secure `http://` URLs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with the App Transport security, after enabling it, it worked fine with the following sets of code in iOS 11,

Also the above URL that you have provided seems to have associated https link, please use either https link or allow App Transport security

```
let avPlayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        let url = URL(string: "https://transom.org/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/stereo_40kbps.mp3?_=7")!
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        avPlayerVC.player = player

        present(avPlayerVC, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
```

But here I have used AVPlayerViewController and used the same instance of AVPlayer as you used in your code.
I don't know how you are using the AVPlayer in your case, but the above case worked fine.

Comment: I'm using AVPlayer and my videos are already served over HTTPS (I've even put an assertion failure for HTTP just to be sure), but still getting the same error.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu : I should have worked, ok there could be one another case where it could fail, make the url which you pass to AVURLAsset(url: URL) with the url generated using the example (Example: let url = yourVideoURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed) ). Because invalid characters in the link could also cause the issue.

Comment: Interesting. There aren't ANY non-alphanumeric characters, they all look like (I'm obfuscating the real URL here) `https://abc123.cloudfront.net/abc123456`. nothing to be escaped, no fragments, nothing to encode/decode. but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Did anyone here figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

same error.
I've solved with server-side work.
remove HSTS header "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000" from http response, disappear error and work fine. I don't know the cause..
request : https://abc.../aaaa.mp3

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, we've tried to set all the headers on server side to **inactive/active**

Finally `unset range` was set to `inactive` and then it worked.