# Error=-25300 from AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When I use `AVPlayerItem(url: customUrl)` from my app I get following runtime error:

```
CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}
```

The error is harmless, it just spams my console. The funny thing is I only get this error from main app, not from keyboard extension where the exact same code resides. It should be noted I'm accessing a **https** url with a .mp3 file. Any ideas how to silence the runtime error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't play mp3 file over HTTP via AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434004/cant-play-mp3-file-over-http-via-avplayer)

Comment: @IllyaBakurov Finally had time to look at it. No even with Allow Arbitrary Loads set to true we still get the error. Also we're calling HTTPS and everything works except we get a warning.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. I'm running http//doimain/playlist.m3u8 video url.. when project sample its working but not for my url #AVP player

Comment: The error code corresponds with [`errSecItemNotFound`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1542001-security_framework_result_codes/errsecitemnotfound?language=objc), for what that's worth.

Comment: And so, this might be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error, namely that the server may be requesting a client TLS certificate on connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CredStore Perform Query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099940/credstore-perform-query-error)

Comment: You can check Error Code Here
https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-25300

Answer (score 1):

This is an error when system tries to access the keychain item and which is not found. Refer [Link](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-54/Keychain/SecBase.h) for more information

> @constant **errSecItemNotFound** The item cannot be found.
>
> errSecItemNotFound           = -25300

So internally AVFoundation, Speech To Text like frameworks are using Keychain itself.

If you are getting this issue in your own codes:

Refer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46806008/5215474)